# Magento 2.1.x Extension Installation

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, installation, magento2.1.5

I am trying to install some extension with the way thats described in the docs.

I uploaded the unziped folder in my root directory and ran the command `php f bin/magento setup:upgrade`

this threw me the following error: `Could not open input file: f`

So I tried to replace f with the folder of my extension and entered

```
php dpd_magento bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

but nothing happened.

When I do it without the dpd_magento it works through some process but the extension, doesn't seem to be installed either way.

Edit

Seems that the module name is stated wrong - I can't find anything thats matching the commented name - see the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

edit:

You try to install a Magento 1.x module to Magento 2.x. Those are not compatible.

---

You mistyped the command, it should be:

```
bin/magento module:enable dpd_magento

{magento executable} module:{command} {your module name}
```

For further information see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html

Alternatively you can execute as a php command like:

```
php bin/magento module:enable dpd_magento
```

Comment: php bin/magento module:enable dpd_magento throws Unknown module(s): 'dpd_magento'

Comment: That's because it's not the correct module name then. Go to the app code folder and look for a folder named like this `<vendor>_<modulename>`. That's the string you need to put in then. This also only works if you put the module at the right place.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: You misplaced your code. You need to put the `app/code` directory in `dpd_magento` into the magento `app/code` directory. Better way would be to install via composer if that method is available.

Comment: But on a second thought...I edited my answer.

Comment: https://www.dpd.com/ro_en/home/e_commerce_extensions/magento - doesn't it say v2 ?

Comment: I guess that's version two of the plugin. That code doesn't look Magento 2 to me. Ask the provider for support.

Comment: Might be ... it's a drag that the client requires DPD, which isn't a small delivery service at all. I have nearly the same issue in another Webstore.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to activate module

In your magento root folder open ctrl+shift - open window command and paste

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Then you need to deploy static content after cleaning the cache

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without adding 'f'

try just simple one, like

Step : 1 Go to root folder and run,

```
php bin/magento module:enable Module_Name

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Step: 2

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Step: 3

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Step: 4

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

and see the status of your module

Comment: php bin/magento module:enable dpd_magento throws Unknown module(s): 'dpd_magento'

Comment: try the command php bin/magento module:status first

Comment: and see wheather your module is listed in the disabled module list or not

Comment: It it is listed in the disabled module list, then type the name exactly similar to shown in the list, and then write php bin/magento module:enable YOUR_MODULE_NAME

Comment: Its not listed in either one of the lists ...

Comment: @noa-dev you have misplaced the module. Revert all changes, put the dpd_magento folder under app/code. Clean the cache, repeat the commands told in my answer. And thats it. It will work 100%

Comment: ok, I'll try that!

Comment: I moved it to app/code and tried the first command again - I still get Unknown module(s): 'dpd_magento'